# Build Controller failing to start on TFS 2013 "Service cannot be started. The handle is invalid”

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

After cloning a 2010 TFS server, upgrading the clone's OS to 2012R2, upgrading SQL Server to 2012 SP2 (11.0.5343), uninstalling TFS 2010, and upgrading to TFS 2013 with update 5, we are running into issues starting the Build Service on the clone.

I've removed the agents and build controllers referencing the other original server through Manage Build Controllers, in Visual Studio 2013.

I've tried to use the TFS 2013 upgrade wizard and it fails when attempting to start the build service so I tried to unconfigure: "tfsconfig.exe setup /uninstall:TeamBuild" and reconfigure through the TFS 2013 upgrade wizard but it yielded the same result.

The TFS database server, Build Server, controller, and agent are located on the same box

For measure, I've even deleted the agents, controllers, and Unregistered and Registered the Build Service in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console as both the batch account used on the original server but that failed so to rule out authentication, I used my domain account (I'm a Local Admin, SQL Server Admin, and TFS Admin) but still had the same result with both accounts.

The Windows event log states “Service cannot be started. The handle is invalid”.

I'm not sure what else could be missed does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Is there anything in the Windows event logs?

Comment: The Windows **event** log states “Service cannot be started. The handle is invalid”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were over 100 Microsoft patches/updates applied over the weekend and the issue went away.  Microsoft confirmed that the issue was related to the OS, not the TFS configuration or installation/upgrade.

Thanks for all your suggestions.  Hopefully this will help someone else out if they are in the same situation and spinning wheels to find the answer.  Keep your systems as up to date as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove build service by going to Team Foundation Server Administration Console, select server name, and click **Remove Feature**, to remove build service feature, then re-configure it.

[image]

Comment: I didn't do this through the UI but after doing so, I found that it's the same thing as the manual step that I executed: "tfsconfig.exe setup /uninstall:TeamBuild" and reconfigure through the TFS 2013 upgrade wizard...  Fortunately, everything completes but unfortunately, the service fails to start.

Comment: Are you able to install a new build service on another machine?