# TFS 2013 Build Service cannot start 503 service unavailable

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

My TFS 2013 Build service cannot run after our IT administrator change password of service account.

I've try many ways like change password and reapply account, remove build configuration and reinstall it but it's still error.
I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 with all updated patches.

My error's as same as this guy [Build Controller failing to start on TFS 2013 "Service cannot be started. The handle is invalid”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395795/build-controller-failing-to-start-on-tfs-2013-service-cannot-be-started-the-ha)

You can view the image below for more information.

Please help me, thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Are you able to access your build server on TFS application tier machine? Are you able to access http://tfsserver:8080/tfs? Check Event log in Event Viewer to see whether there is useful information.

Comment: Hi @Cece-MSFT, I'm still able to access tfsserver:8080/tfs on tfs app machine. In Event viewer I saw a error that related our changed account but I don't know is it really our build service problem or not? It's: TF53010, TF221122 an occured running job Incremental Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation Server TEAM FOUNDATION. Failed to process analysis database (type warehouseexception)

Comment: Are you able to access your build server on TFS application tier machine?  Do you have a spare machine to set up a new build server to see whether the issue persists on the new machine?

Comment: Yes I can access build server from TFS app tier machine. I don't have a spare machine to check but from my build server I can add build service to this own tfs collection without any issue so I think the problem is connection with tfs app tier machine.

Comment: You may turn off the anti-virus software and firewall on your AT machine to see whether the issue persists. Also, when you re-configure your build server, try to rename it to see what would happen.

Comment: Thanks @Cece-MSFT it's my fault when not update sharepoint service account on TFS app machine but I don't know why. There are no clear error message log about this on my build server. It's so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found our problem this's a sharepoint service account not updated with new password. I don't know the relationship between sharepoint and build service but it works now.

Hope this help someone.